# Dynamic tabindex

Tags: php, html

I have a lot of rows, each row has a column with only `<input type='text'/>` , like this:

**html:**

```
<table>
    <tr> 
        <td><input type="text" size="10"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="10"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="10"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" size="10"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="10"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="10"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**php:**

```
while(!$res->EOF)
{
       // then come another while() from other db consult
       while(!$res2->EOF)
       {
           // this create the dynamic columms.
       }
}
```

I'm creating this rows from a db result, and the numbers of columns is dynamic, sometimes more and sometimes less.

I need the tabindex follow the current column "vertical mode".

I made a exp: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbXLu/3/)

Any question, please.

Thanks.

Comment: Show your PHP code here that determines the number of columns in a row.  What conditions determine this?

Comment: my php code dont have any treatmant for this, he just have a while() that comes with the results

Comment: OK...so how do you determine whether a row has more columns from another?

Comment: i have another while inside, that come from another db consult

Comment: count the number of "dynamic" rows and columns and add it to the tabindex for each cell in a row. Or what's the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know how many rows you have.  Your tab indices will look like this:

```
1    6    11
2    7    12
3    8    13
4    9    14
5    10   15
```

Here is the formula for getting the index of each cell:

```
tabindex=rowNum+(rowCount*colnumber)
```

I will leave the implementation as an exercise to the reader.